random interval pulse for triggering sound effect
I am working on a small project using a cheap chinese MP3 player module, that can be triggered to play an mp3 by just sending it a pulse on one of its inputs.
The modules are of this type: https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/1005006734964038.html
I want to use this for halloween props, i have ravens and mice that are situated throughout the setup we create at a scouts troop place for the kids. The idea is that the kids can do a 'scavanger hunt' and locate them. To help the smallest kids a bit, i would like to add sound to them at random intervals.
What the circuit is supposed to do: wait a random amount of time, then send a pulse of around 0.5 seconds, then wait a random amount of time..
That time should be somewhere between 1 to 30 seconds.
I know the possibility to use some CPU or arduino and using 555 timers to make a trigger, but i lack a PIC programmer, and i don't want to spend an entire CPU on it, the costs add up quick with those considering i'll need about 20 of those. I'm sure there's a cheap/easy solution for it, i just don't know it and can't find it.. I hope somebody here can at least point me in the right direction or has a solution!

If you're going to disallow MCUs and 555s, the two most obvious solutions, you're going to have to be more specific about what you will allow. Are you up for building a two-transistor astable multivibrator?

It does make me a bit suspicious that this thing has a lot of positive reviews that explicitly say "hey, I haven't tested this yet, but here's five out of five stars".

the cheap easy solution is an entire CPU on a board with momeory ready to program, the whole module costing less than a coffee (coughee Arduino coughee)

this may help with cost https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYhAGnsnO7w

Depending on how much you value your own time, I would suggest going the Arduino Nano clone route. They go for about 5$ each and will save your loads of time and will leave you with a bunch of MCU-boards for future projects :-)
You can go the route of building some dedicated hardware, but that will also not be free (guessing it will probably also cost about 1$ in parts only) and the end product will never be useful for other projects.
Is the random interval requirement firm? Without that it's actually quite simple using a RC-circuit - Schmitt Trigger IC - RC-circuit.


I know the possibility to use some CPU or arduino and using 555 timers to make a trigger,

yes, a microcontroller is 100% the way to go here if you want long, random delays. Least component count, lowest complexity, lowest power usage, easiest to get right reliably.

but i lack a PIC programmer

You don't need a PIC programmer if you don't plan on programming a PIC microcontroller. And it doesn't sound like you want to: the Arduino family doesn't (as far as I remember) even include anything based on a PIC. And you wouldn't necessarily even use an arduino.

and i don't want to spend an entire CPU on it, the costs add up quick with those considering i'll need about 20 of those.

I don't think you actually did the math. Simple, easy-to-program microcontroller modules are 2€ to 5€ these days, and can be had for even less if one accepts minor inconveniences. So, that's going to be, as said, the least part-count and consequenty, for your small run of devices, the most cost-efficient solution. If you start building randomized timers with a long time constant like you want, it's very hard to imagine you'll build something 20 times for a price that low.

I'm sure there's a cheap/easy solution for it, i just don't know it and can't find it

Yes, microcontrollers with integrated bootloader that make programming them from a laptop/PC easy. Technically, you could probably also save yourself the MP3 modules, and integrate that functionality into your microcontroller, assuming it has enough memory for a short sound snippet, and the means to output that in a somewhat feasible manner. But for easy of use, you're probably fine with your pre-made MP3 players (if they work. I've learned to never trust aliexpress products to actually do 100% what the product page says).
For example, the ESP32*-w-* series of microcontroller modules sound like what you'd need. The ESP32-C3-WROOM-02 can be had for < 2.50€ in your quantities, and for programming them you will need 1 (one) USB-to-TTL UART converter, which ideally also outputs a 3.3V supply voltage (they usually do), so, that's another 5 to 10€.
You will need a (cheap) soldering iron, to connect wires to the Supply voltage, ground, and temporarily the 2 programming UART lines, as well as the line going to your MP3 module. I don't know what your power supply looks like, or what voltage your MP3 player modules need (these seem to come without any documentation, how will you know how to use them?), but the ESP32 module will want a supply between 3V and 3.6V, so you might need to add a linear regulator (something like the venerable xx1117 series) for 3.3V to it.
If you dislike the idea of soldering, for ~2,40€ to 4€ a piece, there's also eval boards from other vendors with a less well-known ecosystem, see for example this digikey category listing. How the documentation looks like for a "AI thinker PB-03F"? Who knows.
If in doubt, a sensible ESP8266 board, even if slightly older, would do as well. MicroPython works on ESP8266 boards (and some ESP32, for example the ESP-C3 mentioned above), and probably would be a really nice way to build something that turns on a pin for 0.5s quickly. You can, but you don't have to, use the WLAN functionality of these modules (e.g. to connect them all to your own wifi, should you decide to set up something where you have a central computer in your wifi that dispenses commands to the individual props, instead of them having individually random intervals.
